# Getting different response in Restsharp then in Postman

Tags: c#, rest, http, postman, restsharp

I am getting a correct response when using Postman but when I use the generated restsharp code in Postman i get the following as a response "Not available at this moment".

The generated Code is the following:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://allevents.in/api/index.php/events/web/q");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Postman-Token", "e35b163d-19b5-bb1d-ddcc-b547411efeac");
request.AddHeader("Referer", "allevents.in");
request.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("scheme", "https");
request.AddHeader("path", "/api/index.php/events/web/q");
request.AddHeader("method", "POST");
request.AddHeader("autority", "allevents.in");
request.AddParameter("undefined", "{\"venue\":\"0\",\"ids\":\"0\",\"type\":\"json\",\"city\":\"luxembourg\",\"edate\":\"\",\"page\":\"0\",\"keywords\":\"0\",\"sdate\":\"\",\"category\":\"parties\",\"city_display\":\"luxembourg\"}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

I have tried clearing the default parameters but had no success.

Thanks in advance

**Solved**

There were two missing cookies that were not shown in the postman interface.I have found them in the fiddler request and added them to the cookie container.

Answer (score 0):

Man, try remove the Postman-token.

Before I remove this, I got "Not avaliable", After I remove I got the correct message...

```
{
  "request": {
    "venue": "0",
    "ids": "0",
    "type": "json",
    "city": "luxembourg",
    "edate": "",
    "page": "0",
    "keywords": "0",
    "sdate": "",
    "category": "parties",
    "city_display": "luxembourg",
    "rows": 50
  },
  "count": 50,
  "item": [
    {
      "event_id": "156123315020311",
      "eventname": "Soho - All Must Dance",
      "eventname_raw": "Soho - All Must Dance",
      "owner_id": "283436232149109",
      "thumb_url": "https://cdn-az.allevents.in/banners/8b8744b8ad6d3e89749c1276d0d37d60-rimg-w200-h200-gmir.jpg",
      .....
```